# How query execution done in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 and would really like to know how the engine executes queries.

Let's suppose I run this query :

```
select * from <table1> with(nolock)
```

or same with a join:

```
select * from <table1> a with(nolock) 
join <table2> b with(nolock) on a.<column1> = b.<column1> 
where <some condition>
```

How does the query work behind the scene?
Is there any way to see actual steps that are performed for execution and showing results?

Comment: Kind of very vague question could you explain more in detail what you are trying to ask? Like what do you mean by flow? Does that mean the interface flow or the actual backend machine coded execution?

Comment: There are very long books on this topic.  If you have a specific question, please ask it.  If you want general information, there are tons of reference materials available, but this is no the place.

Comment: Actually i wanted to know this,
 Logical Query Processing Phases in Brief

Comment: @VikrantMore - That is different from your question. Logical = Conceptual. The actual steps that are performed = Physical and may be very different. [See Itzik's Poster](http://tsql.solidq.com/books/insidetsql2008/Logical%20Query%20Processing%20Poster.pdf)

Comment: @VikrantMore - No it doesn't. The logical query processing phase is just a conceptual model. The query optimiser applies transformation rules and comes up with a physical plan that maintains the same semantics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The database engine analyses the query and selects the best way of retrieving the requested data under the current conditions.

See [Displaying Graphical Execution Plans (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071.aspx).

Comment: yes you are right; but Actually i wanted to know this, Logical Query Processing Phases in Brief

Answer (score -1):

LISTING 1-1 Logical query processing step numbers

```
(5) SELECT (5-2) DISTINCT (5-3) TOP(<top_specification>) (5-1) <select_list> (1) FROM (1-J) <left_table> <join_type> JOIN <right_table> ON <on_predicate> | (1-A) <left_table> <apply_type> APPLY <right_table_expression> AS <alias> | (1-P) <left_table> PIVOT(<pivot_specification>) AS <alias>| (1-U) <left_table> UNPIVOT(<unpivot_specification>) AS <alias> (2) WHERE <where_predicate> (3) GROUP BY <group_by_specification> (4) HAVING <having_predicate> (6) ORDER BY <order_by_list>;
```

Logical Query Processing Phases in Brief

■ (1) FROM The FROM phase identiﬁ es the query’s source tables and processes table
operators. Each table operator applies a series of subphases. For example, the phases
involved in a join are (1-J1) Cartesian Product, (1-J2) ON Filter, (1-J3) Add Outer Rows.
The FROM phase generates virtual table VT1.

■ (1-J1) Cartesian Product This phase performs a Cartesian product (cross join) between
the two tables involved in the table operator, generating VT1-J1.

■ (1-J2) ON Filter This phase ﬁ lters the rows from VT1-J1 based on the predicate that
appears in the ON clause (). Only rows for which the predicate evaluates
to TRUE are inserted into VT1-J2.
(1-J3) Add Outer Rows If OUTER JOIN is speciﬁ ed (as opposed to CROSS JOIN or
INNER JOIN), rows from the preserved table or tables for which a match was not found
are added to the rows from VT1-J2 as outer rows, generating VT1-J3.

■ (2) WHERE This phase ﬁ lters the rows from VT1 based on the predicate that appears in
the WHERE clause (). Only rows for which the predicate evaluates to
TRUE are inserted into VT2.

■ (3) GROUP BY This phase arranges the rows from VT2 in groups based on the column
list speciﬁ ed in the GROUP BY clause, generating VT3. Ultimately, there will be one
result row per group.

■ (4) HAVING This phase ﬁ lters the groups from VT3 based on the predicate that
appears in the HAVING clause (). Only groups for which the
predicate evaluates to TRUE are inserted into VT4.

■ (5) SELECT This phase processes the elements in the SELECT clause, generating VT5.

■ (5-1) Evaluate Expressions This phase evaluates the expressions in the SELECT list,
generating VT5-1.

■ (5-2) DISTINCT This phase removes duplicate rows from VT5-1, generating VT5-2.

■ (5-3) TOP This phase ﬁ lters the speciﬁ ed top number or percentage of rows from
VT5-2 based on the logical ordering deﬁ ned by the ORDER BY clause, generating the
table VT5-3.

■ (6) ORDER BY This phase sorts the rows from VT5-3 according to the column list
speciﬁ ed in the ORDER BY clause, generating the cursor VC6.